# Hover Drop Down Menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am hoping to create a hover down menu in a website that I am helping maintain. This is the nav bar code. I am hoping to make "Work With Us" have several drop down menu options. Any suggestions? I've tried following this, but haven't had luck. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

```
  <div id="navtoggle">
    <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center navlinkdiv">
        <div>
                <a href="/uwchips" class="svgbtn" title="Go to main home page"><img class="svgicon" src="/uwchips/img/home.svg" alt="home icon" /></a>
            </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#thenavbar" class="svgbtn navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" title="expand and collapse menu"><img class="svgicon" src="/uwchips/img/hamburger.svg" alt="expand menu icon" /></a>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="thenavbar" class="collapse">
    <h2 class="offscreen">Site Navigation</h2>
    <div id="topnavlist" class="navbar-nav align-content-between align-items-center">
        <div class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/uwchips/">Home</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/uwchips/about-us">About Us</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/uwchips/people">People</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/uwchips/projects">Projects</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/uwchips/work-with-us">Work With Us</a>
        <div class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/uwchips/products">Products</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look like you use **Bootstrap@4** . Try this https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do with some simple CSS code. I have edited your html a little, though, because this doesn't work unless the two elements are on the same level, but the gist of it is this: You have your hovering element:

```
<a href="#thenavbar" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" 
title="expand and collapse menu"><img class="svgicon" 
src="http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i86425/martin-berube/flat-
animal/duck.ico" alt="expand menu icon" width="50px"/></a>
```

Then you have your div of the actual navbar:

```
<div id="thenavbar" class="collapse">
<h2 class="offscreen">Site Navigation</h2>
<div id="topnavlist" class="navbar-nav align-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#example">Home</a></div>
    <div class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#example">About Us</a></div>
    <div class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#example">People</a></div>
    <div class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#example">Projects</a></div>
    <div class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#example">Work With Us</a>
    <div class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#example">Products</a></div>
</div>
```

Now that you have that, you add your CSS code:

```
#thenavbar {
  visibility:hidden;
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
}

.navbar-toggler:hover ~ #thenavbar {
  visibility:visible;
}
```

The finished product is below, and hovering over the duck will show your navbar:

```css
#thenavbar {
  visibility:hidden;
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
}

 .navbar-toggler:hover ~ #thenavbar {
  visibility:visible;
  
}

#thenavbar:hover {
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<a href="#thenavbar" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" title="expand and collapse menu"><img class="svgicon" src="http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i86425/martin-berube/flat-animal/duck.ico" alt="expand menu icon" width="50px"/></a>

<div id="thenavbar" class="collapse">
    <h2 class="offscreen">Site Navigation</h2>
    <div id="topnavlist" class="navbar-nav align-content-between align-items-center">
        <div class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#example">Home</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#example">About Us</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#example">People</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#example">Projects</a></div>
        <div class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#example">Work With Us</a>
        <div class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#example">Products</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```